# JupyterHub user pod can't assume EKS node role

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, jupyterhub

I installed JupyterHub with Helm on an EKS cluster, although the EKS service role can be correctly assumed by the hub pod (whose name starts with "hub-"), the user pods (starting with "jupyter-USERNAME") seem can't assume the role. Because of this, when a user uses boto3 in her notebook, she is asked for her IAM user credentials, which is not ideal.

All other pods in that namespace can assume the EKS role automatically except for the JupyterHub user pods. May I have your advice on this please? Thanks everyone for your time and consideration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to configure the `service_account` for your kube_spawner.
https://jupyterhub-kubespawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spawner.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The issue has been solved by using the kube2iam tool. Thanks again.